# How to join two tables with average function and where clause? SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables below with the following information

```
project.analytics 
        | proj_id | list_date  | state  
        |   1     |   03/05/10 |   CA   
        |   2     |   04/05/10 |   WA   
        |   3     |   03/05/10 |   WA   
        |   4     |   04/05/10 |   CA   
        |   5     |   03/05/10 |   WA   
        |   6     |   04/05/10 |   CA   

employees.analytics 
        | employee_id  | proj_id  | worked_date
        |   20         |   1      | 3/12/10    
        |   30         |   1      | 3/11/10         
        |   40         |   2      | 4/15/10     
        |   50         |   3      | 3/16/10     
        |   60         |   3      | 3/17/10     
        |   70         |   4      | 4/18/10
```

What query can I write to determine the average number of unique employees who have worked on the project **in the first 7 days** that it was listed by **month and state?**

Desired output:

```
     | list_date | state  | # Unique Employees of projects first 7 day list 
     |   March   |   CA   |   1
     |   April   |   WA   |   2
     |   July    |   WA   |   2
     |   August  |   CA   |   1
```

My Attempt

```
    select 
        month(list_date),
        state_name, 
        count(*) as Projects,
    from projects 
    group by
        month(list_date),
        state_name;
```

I understand the next steps are to subtract the worked_date - list_date and if value is <7 then average count of employees from the 2nd table but I'm not sure what query functions to use.

Comment: Have you tried anything?  You should show your efforts.  Also explain what "an average number of unique employees is".  I don't understand how that would be calculated.

Comment: Yes! - I can write my attempt right now

Comment: I'm stuck at writing the query to be able to get the data from employees.analytics (2nd table) to average count when the worked_date is <7 days from the list_date of the employees.analytics (1st table).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a CASE with a DISTINCT to COUNT the unique employees that worked within the first 7 days of the list_date.

Once you have that total of employees per project, then you can calculate those averages per month & state.

```sql
SELECT 
 MONTHNAME(list_date) as `ListMonth`,
 state,
 AVG(TotalUniqEmp7Days) AS `Average Unique Employees of projects first 7 day list`
FROM
( 
   SELECT 
     proj.proj_id,
     proj.list_date,
     proj.state,
     COUNT(DISTINCT CASE 
                    WHEN emp.worked_date BETWEEN proj.list_date and DATE_ADD(proj.list_date, INTERVAL 6 DAY)
                    THEN emp.employee_id
                    END) AS TotalUniqEmp7Days
     -- , COUNT(DISTINCT emp.employee_id) AS TotalUniqEmp
     FROM project.analytics proj
     LEFT JOIN employees.analytics emp ON emp.proj_id = proj.proj_id
     GROUP BY proj.proj_id, proj.list_date, proj.state
) AS ProjectTotals
GROUP BY YEAR(list_date), MONTH(list_date), MONTHNAME(list_date), state;
```

A Sql Fiddle test can be found [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6c625/2/0)

Comment: Hi LukStorms - thanks for your input. This might seem like a very dumb question but is proj.proj_id the same syntax as project.analytics.proj_id. How do you select the table name with the field name if the table name is labeled as project.analytics?

Comment: @JuniorSQLearner In the SQL "proj" is an alias name for the actual table "project.analytics". A short name is easier to use and prefix the column names. I could have just used 1 letter "p" for it, or whatever.  If 2 table have fields with the same names, you need to prefix them with the table, or the alias for it. So that the database engine knows which one you mean.

Comment: That makes sense - where did you set the alias name in SQL? Is it when you wrote FROM project.analytics proj and LEFT JOIN employees.analytics emp. I assume when you first refer to the table like that, you can use it subsequently thereafter?

Comment: Luk this is extremely helpful - I don't know if this is too much to ask but your answer is currently beyond my SQL experience/knowledge right now. Could you write a query where you subtract worked_date from table 2 with list_date table 1 and if its less than 7, you count average the # of distinct employees? This was the approach I was thinking when trying to tackle this problem

Comment: @JuniorSQLearner At least check out the link in the answer. It's a test.  I split it up in 2 queries, the first with the totals is based on the sub-query of the second.

Comment: @JuniorSQLearner I think you mean something like checking on 
`DATEDIFF(emp.worked_date, proj.list_date) < 7`

Comment: However, if you check on the DATEDIFF then you're assuming that there are no working dates before the list date. Because a negative DATEDIFF is also lower than 7.

Comment: Luk - what is the sequence of thought process when writing on this query? I'm struggling on knowing where to start whenever encountering a problem like this. For example the sequence of count, from left join, group? Could you provide some insight on your thoughts of the order? Thanks- this would be extremely invaluable. for me.

Comment: Lateral thinking + Using the language
+ Knowledge.  And if that doesn't help, google for inspiration.

Comment: It's just that the more you use a language like Sql, and learn to understand it's abilities and tricks, the easier it gets to connect the dots. In this case I figured that the average couldn't be calculated directly, so it had to be grouped again.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is the code that you want

```
select
p.list_date, p.state,
emp.no_of_unique_emp 
from project.analytics p
inner join (
  select
  t.project_id,
  count(t.employee_id) as no_of_unique_emp
  from (
    select distinct employee_id, project_id
    from employees.analytics
  ) t
  group by t.project_id
) emp
on emp.project_id = p.project_id
where datediff (p.list_date, getdate()) <= 7
```

Comment: Does someone mind putting an SQL fiddle for this link?